# Can an object's member function modify another object?

Tags: c++, member-functions, this-pointer

Today's question is, can an object modify another object of the same class type? For example imagine that a class has some private data members. We create two objects of that class type. How can one object modify the other object? Is is legal to do so?

Can we write a member function which gives an object the ability to modify another object of the same class type? This could be useful if an object represents a fighter in a video game, and you want to give one fighter the ability to wound another one.

Turns out that it's possible to do this in C++. We want to understand why C++ gives us the ability to do this. Do do so, we must first understand what a member function actually is and how it works. Read the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a `class Bucket` with two private data members. There is also a constructor, a copy constructor, and some other functions. Let us turn our attention to `modifyOther` function. It takes a single parameter, which is a pointer to a `Bucket` object. Then that member function can edit that other `Bucket` object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bucket {
  public:
    // Acts as constructor acceptint two arguments x and y,
    // one argument x,
    // or no arguments (default constructor).
    Bucket(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}

    Bucket(const Bucket& rhs)
    {
        this->x = rhs.x;
        this->y = rhs.y;
    }

    void modifyOther(Bucket* other)
    {
        other->x = -1;
        other->y = 1;
    }

    void printInfo()
    {
        cout << "x = " << this->x << endl;
        cout << "y = " << this->y << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
  private:
    int x;
    int y;
};


int main()
{
    Bucket a(10, 5);
    a.printInfo();

    Bucket b(8, 9);
    b.printInfo();

    a.modifyOther(&b);

    a.printInfo();
    b.printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

In the `main()` function, we are declaring two objects of `class Base` type. Notice that they are the same data type. That is important. Then we call object `a`'s `modifyOther` function to successfully modify the internal private data members of object `b`.

Here is the output of this code:

```
x = 10
y = 5

x = 8
y = 9

x = 10
y = 5

x = -1
y = 1
```

Now you may be thinking, shouldn't this be illegal? Aren't private data members only allowed to be accessed by the object itself? It turns out that the member access specifiers like `private` and `public` are enforced by the compiler, and the compiler has no concept of individual objects, only classes.

`private` data members are allowed to be accessed by anything inside of their class, allowed to be accessed by the class's member functions. Since `modifyOther` is a member function of type `class Base`, it can access the `private` variables `int x` and `int y` and change them. Hence no rule is being violated here.

What is a member function? It is simply a stand alone function which takes an "invisible" pointer to the calling object, and it accesses the object through that pointer. That pointer is called `this`. Look at the `printInfo` function. There is a reason why I used `this->y` to indicate the member variables. Because all member functions take an "invisible" `this` pointer to the calling object, the function actually looks like:

```
void printInfo(Bucket* this)
{
    cout << "x = " << this->x << endl;
    cout << "y = " << this->y << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // this->x = -1;
}
```

Notice that I added the last extra line to this function on purpose. Compare the definition of `printInfo` function to `modifyOther` function. They look very similar. In fact the only difference is the name of the `Bucket*` parameter! `Bucket* this` is the implicit pointer to the calling object. `Bucket* other` is just a pointer to some other `Bucket` object. The compiler is "dumb", it can't tell the difference between these two `Bucket *`s based on their names alone. It treats them the same! So we can conclude that the same mechanism that is used to modify the calling object can also be used to modify another object of the same class type.

Keep in mind that we cannot use the same trick to pass in a pointer to an object of *another* class type and modify it. That will not work. A member function has access only to variables that are *in the same class*! `private` means that the variable can only be modified by member functions of *that particular* class, not any other ones. A `priavte` variable cannot be modified by the outside world, so the outside world also includes any member functions of different classes.

If you don't understand this topic, please look at my similar question on StackOverflow, and also please watch this YouTube video that I found while researching this topic.

[Are there multiple member functions compiled for each C++ object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917382/are-there-multiple-member-functions-compiled-for-each-c-object/53917427#53917427)

[What is the 'this' pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Wv-lEl1sgg&t=0s

Comment: This answer makes it sound like the behavior is a shortcoming of compilers, and it might be better if the language would prevent objects of the same type from accessing each other.  But it's actually an intentional language feature.  Without it, it would be annoying to implement even common things like copy/move constructors, assignment operators, comparison operators, and swap functions.

Comment: And the C++ language and compilers certainly could treat access via `this` (explicitly or implicitly) differently from other member accesses - in fact, it does make a difference for using `protected` members in some cases.